# How can I reject and close connections in django-channels 2?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, disconnect

It's been 1 month since I started using django-channels and now I have a feeling that I am not disconnecting websockets properly.
When I disconnect I want to destroy the group completely if no one is there and it should be no sign of existence.
When I'm rejecting connections I raise channels.exceptions.DenyConnection or send {'accepted': 'False'}
I was just wondering if this is the right way to do things that I've mentioned or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've understood this, the way to close a group is by using group_discard.

```
def disconnect(self, close_code):
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("yourgroupname", self.channel_name)
```

Without having tested this, I would assume that raising an exception would result in an error 500 at the client. And a client receiving an error would probably interpret that not as "closed normally".

See channel docs here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#groups

Answer (score 10):

Try calling `self.close()`

[From the channels Documentation:](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#websocketconsumer)

```py
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        # Called on connection.
        # To accept the connection call:
        self.accept()
        # Or accept the connection and specify a chosen subprotocol.
        # A list of subprotocols specified by the connecting client
        # will be available in self.scope['subprotocols']
        self.accept("subprotocol")
        # To reject the connection, call:
        self.close()
```

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that if you `close` before doing `accept`, any close-code is not sent to the client. `accept` is needed before closing for the code to be sent - seems like a mistake to me?

Comment: Also, `close` should be awaited. Like this `await self.close()`